# Optimization of this algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

```
def check_rule(token, training_data, mode):
    if mode == "frag":
        children = training_data["words"]
        remove = list.remove
        def in_child(x):
            for i in token:
                if i not in x:
                    return False
                remove(x, i)
            return True

        for i in children:
            if in_child(i):
                return False
        return True

        # is_present = children.map(in_child)
    elif mode == "wild":

        # is_present = training_data[1].map(methodcaller("__contains__", token))

        for i in training_data[1]:
            if token in i:
                return False
        return True

    elif mode == "prefix":
        # is_present = training_data[1].str.startswith(token)

        token_len = len(token)
        for i in training_data[1]:
            if i[:token_len] == token:
                return False
        return True

        # token_len = len(token)
        # is_present = training_data[1].str[:token_len] == token

        # is_present = training_data[1].map(methodcaller("startswith", token))

    for i in is_present:
        if i:
            return False
    return True
```

This function takes in:

`token`: string
`training_data`: A pandas dataframe with 2 columns having *ID* and *vendor name* columns
`mode`: Which can be any one of the `prefix`, `wild`, `frag`.

The commented parts are the optimizations I tried after profiling. But, it still takes a lot of time. Can this be optimized further?

Comment: this may better belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what does `for i in is_present:
        if i:
            return False` do if `is_present` isn't initialized?

Comment: That part is not being called.

Comment: if `mode` doesn't equal what you want it does

Comment: all those `for` loops checking a condition could be faster using `any`/`all`. And there's room for dictionaries somewhere...

Comment: @depperm I am not sending anything other than the 3 values for ```mode```.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I can give a function to ```any``` to evaluate. Can I? The last outside ```if elif``` part can be done using ```any``` though.

Comment: @depperm how can I transfer this question to codereview. Or should I ask it again there?

Comment: ask it again there